# How can I set the email sender name?

Tags: 8

below code is not working in our custom module.

```
$site_name = \Drupal::config('system.site')->get('name');
$site_mail = \Drupal::config('system.site')->get('mail');

$message['headers']['From'] = $site_name . ' <' . $site_mail . '>';
$message['headers']['Sender'] = $message['headers']['Return-Path'] = $site_mail;
$message['from'] = $site_name . ' <' . $site_mail . '>';

It gives the output like this : 

 MailSender <MailSender> <email@example.com>
```

and I want the output like this :

```
MailSender <email@example.com>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at your code and the output you wrote, it come clearly out, that either:

- $message['headers']['From'] = $site_name . ' <' . $site_mail . '>';
- $message['from'] = $site_name . ' <' . $site_mail . '>';

is not working at all.

I would get rid of the unnecessary code first, and then trying to modify the working line.